# How to solve 'error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*current` as mutable more than once at a time'

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have the code

```
pub struct node {
    pub key: libc::c_int,
    pub left: Option<Box<node>>,
    pub right: Option<Box<node>>,
}

pub fn min_value_node(node: Option<&mut node>) -> Option<&mut node> {
    let mut current = node?;
    while let Some(left) = current.left.as_deref_mut() {
        current = left;
    }
    Some(current)
}
```

But it has the following error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*current` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/bst.rs:67:10
   |
62 | pub fn min_value_node(node: Option<&mut node>) -> Option<&mut node> {
   |                                    - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
63 |     let mut current = node?;
64 |     while let Some(left) = current.left.as_deref_mut() {
   |                            ------------ first mutable borrow occurs here
...
67 |     Some(current)
   |     -----^^^^^^^-
   |     |    |
   |     |    second mutable borrow occurs here
   |     returning this value requires that `current.left` is borrowed for `'1`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
error: could not compile `bst-rs` (lib) due to previous error
```

How can I re-designe this function (without changing the function signature)?

Comment: As with any problem case 3 error you can split [check and borrow into 2](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=622bea7a81d76d2110497e79296504d1), it's a known limitation of the current borrow checker.